# MSFT Store App: The Failure name is reported as 'Unknown'. Need Advice

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-dev-center

On MSFT Store we are having App Crash (as seen in image).  The Failure name is reported as 'Unknown'.

[image]

The description hit says "Failure names that include !unknown mean that symbols weren’t present".  So my question is how to include symbols in MSFT Store App? so that instead of 'Unknown' we get actual error details.

Also note that we have "include public symbol file" checkbox enabled during package creation. What else we need to do more to ensure we get actual error details ?

[image]

Please advise.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Failure name is reported as 'Unknown'. Need Advice

Please refer to Health report document [Failures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/health-report#failures) part. *At times, you may see an entry for Unknown in this section. This occurs when despite our best efforts, **we are unable to collect full details for one or more failures, which will all be grouped together under Unknown. Most often, this occurs because of storage constraints, but it can also be a result of a device's privacy settings, network connection issues**, partial/bad crash dumps, and other factors.*

For getting more bug detail, we suggest use App Center SDK to capture the exception info. And here is [Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/uwp) document your could refer to.